Would adding toads to my farm change the food chain?
I'm a farmer and I'm having trouble with bugs I don't want to use chemicals on my products so if I brought toads into my farm would it change the food chain?

im asking because i dont know what to do

Sounds like it might be too a big of a change for the effect you're aiming at, maybe some other insects that don't damage the crops could help against existing insects. Try to identify or at least take pictures of the 'bad' insects and look for advice from agricultural specialists in the area or from the nearest university that has a department like environmental sciences or ecology, or even if they only have like a biology department they might be able to direct you to some other school or institution.

Not sure if you're allowed to do that, but still: toads need places to live, shelter and breed. A somewhat healthy ecosystem in other words. Thta's not something you can just buy or install.
